# iOS Web App: Use back swipe gesture to go back

Tags: ios, iphone, web, web-applications, progressive-web-apps

I adapted my website according to the official guide over at

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html

Since I made the changes my website looks like an app when I add it as a bookmark to the homescreen. However, my web app relies on the go-back button/gesture even if there is no page refresh. But the gesture does not work out of the box. What can I do to activate it? I read that iOS 12.2 should support the gesture.

Answer (score 1):

This should work when you set your `display` to `standalone` in your webmanifest.

Checkout this link for more documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest#display